# Change URL in Joomla

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-sef-urls

I am using Joomla 2.5 and Sobipro. So when i visit an added entry, the url is **mywebsite.com/menuitem/entryid-entryname** and i want it to be **mywebsite.com/entryname** without the entry id and without the menuitem name. Is that somehow achievable?

Comment: Can you use Search Engine Freindly thirdparty components? cause almost every of them hace this capability to rewrite urls as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SEF Components is te best solution, they have Custom url rewriting tool in their own. 
Use AceSEF :

- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/sef/10019

Great tool for rewriting urls!

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply Mohsenr1. I installed it and it works just fine. But do you know if i can somehow make the urls automatically? Because just think that clients are adding entries all the time and in different categories, so if a new entry is being added, i have to change manually the url of the specific entry in every category.

Comment: The answer is no, it depends on Joomla engine and mod_rewrite in Apache, but if you know how to change rewrite rules in .htaccess file, you may can do it. I can't help with that I'm sorry. The only thing that I can say now, is to migrate to Drupal, if you want automatically have the kind of urls you've mentioned.

Comment: also this article may help you come through this : http://www.itoctopus.com/how-to-remove-the-category-name-from-the-url-in-joomla

Answer (score 0):

You can use sh404SEF Component for url rewrite in joomla 2.5

Awesome Component, use this.